# How to use dependOn entry option in Webpack 5

Tags: javascript, webpack, build

I want to split a Webpack project into multiple entries. I have several entries, most of which depend on a few shared libraries, so I wanted to use the `dependOn` option to avoid duplicating code between modules.

**My issue - the output of an entry with a dependency (defined by `dependOn`) does not produce runnable code.**

My Webpack config is structured something like this:

```js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'production',
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js']
    },
    entry: {
        fizzbuzz: './src/libs/fizzbuzz/index.js',
        foobar:  './src/libs/foobar/index.js',
        main: {
            import: './src/libs/main/index.js',
            dependOn: ['foobar', 'fizzbuzz']
        }
    },
    output: {
        clean: true,
        filename: '[name]/bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    }
}
```

My `main` entry doesn't produce a self-executing function when I add the `dependOn` option - it looks like it pushes it to a dependency graph. (This is the opposite of what I would expect to happen.)

Am I not using this correctly? [The documentation](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/entry-context/#dependencies) doesn't say anything about how to get my entry to run when I include `dependOn`.

I have a minimal reproducible example with the input and output files [here](https://github.com/ConnorJamesLow/webpack-dependOn-mre/tree/main).

Comment: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/discussions